# onclicklistener not working inside fragment

Tags: android

I created one fragment with button but the onclicklistener is not called when i click the button.

Here's my code of fragment class

```
public class UserEntryFragment extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    EditText member_num,password;
    Button submit;
    ProgressBar progressBar;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.main,container, false);
    member_num = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.member_num);
    password = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.password);
    submit = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.submit);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
    submit.setOnClickListener(this);
    return view;
}
   @Override
   public void onClick(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if (view == submit) {
        System.out.println("Button Clicked");
    }
}
```

Am i missing something or doing it in a wrong way?

Thx in advance.

Comment: try `if (view.getId() == R.id.submit) {` and use `Log` instead of System.out.pprintln

Comment: How do you know the onClickListener is not called ?

Comment: @Raghunandan why should it make difference, in this case?

Comment: @blackbelt right. comparing views here. just suggested an alternative